# Set Default time to mobiscroll time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobiscroll

I am using the below code to show`timepicker` when clicking on an input type text. Is there a way to set a `default value` such as `01:00`for the `time picker`??

```
$.plugin($afterSubPageLoad,{
end_time_picker:function()
{
    $(function(){$('#actualHours').scroller({preset: 'time',theme: 'wp',display: 'modal',mode: 'mixed',timeFormat:'HH:ii',timeWheels:'HHii'});});       
}
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You do it with the setValue method:

```
$('#actualHours').mobiscroll('setValue','01:00');
```

Comment: I found that this works for an exact hour i.e. :00 but doesn't work for times off the hour you need to drop the :

  $('#actualHours').mobiscroll('setValue','1315');

Answer (score 0):

Just define the default date or time in the `value` attibute of your `input` element depending on the local date time parameters you are using (yyyy-mm-dd , dd.mm.yyyy, ...) like :

```
<input name="user-select-datetime-to" id="user-select-datetime-to" value="03.07.2013 15:04"/>
```

or

```
<input name="user-select-time-to" id="user-select-time-to" value="10:00"/>
```

Comment: I select time using mobiscroll timepicker... I dont think this can be done in that.. I have tried it.

Comment: I am using it like this with mobiscroll

Comment: `<input class="actualHoursStyle generalInfoInputBoxes" id="actualHours" placeholder="Hrs:Min" value="10:00"/>` This is how i hv done

Answer (score 0):

I know this is older question, but this is what I had to do in order to default the time.

```
 var showModalTimePickerWithDefaultTime = function (defaultTime)
  {
    $('.item-cell.right').mobiscroll().time({
      mode: 'scroller',
      theme: kendo.support.mobileOS.ios ? 'ios' : 'android',
      display: 'modal',
      animate: 'fade',
      dateFormat: '',
      timeFormat: 'hh:ii A',
      dateOrder: 'hhiia'
    });
    $('.item-cell.right').mobiscroll('setValue', defaultTime);
  }
```